# Jenkins with Xvfb plugin: got "Prefix string too short" error on empty build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, xvfb

I created an empty item, check "Start Xvfb before the build, and shut it down after.", and build just failed with error.

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test/workspace
FATAL: Prefix string too short
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Prefix string too short
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1978)
    at hudson.FilePath$18.invoke(FilePath.java:1404)
    at hudson.FilePath$18.invoke(FilePath.java:1401)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:989)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:967)
    at hudson.FilePath.createTempDir(FilePath.java:1401)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.xvfb.XvfbBuildWrapper.launchXvfb(XvfbBuildWrapper.java:484)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.xvfb.XvfbBuildWrapper.setUp(XvfbBuildWrapper.java:594)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:154)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:533)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1718)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
```

What goes wrong?

- Ubuntu Server 14.10
- Jenkins 1.597
- xvfb plugin 1.0.13
- Xvfb executable path: /usr/bin/Xvfb

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Xvfb Jenkins plug-in version 1.0.15 fixes this issue. See also https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26505.